# How to get a working api key for android apps

Tags: api-key, back4app

I'm trying to make api in the easyway with back4app but when I make an api key using console.developer.google.com and paste it I get this error

[image]

so how will I get a working api key for android apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps are described at [this guide](https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/push-notifications/parse-server-push-notifications).

The keys to link your Firebase Project at Back4App are shown at the image below:

[image]

Copy the Server Key and paste it at the API Key field and do the same thing with the Sender ID, copy and paste it at the GCM Sender ID field.

:)

Comment: so I can't start with back4app without having a firebase project?

Comment: Yes, you can start without a Firebase project! The firebase project is only required if you want to integrate Push Notification with your app.

Comment: Feel free to start your Frontend project without Push Notification settings

Comment: it worked thx but can you help me on how can I read all table data because the site examples in crud section has shown how to read one row with a condition but I want to read all the class data

Comment: Hi! Can you please take a look at this guide? https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#basic-queries.